# Refresh Associated Domains iOS

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have universal links working in my app.

I enable the Associated Domains, upload the apple-app-site-association file, and run the app.   All works as expected, the domains are registered (I'm watching via the OS log in Xcode), and I can use Open In from the Notes app to test the links.

HOWEVER.  If I reboot the device (in my case iPad, iOS 10) it ceases to work.   It appears to me as if the associated domains are getting un-registered/forgotten when the device shuts down.

Is there a way to refresh the associated domains on app launch?

I'm already using Branch.io, and this affects those links as well as straight universal links.

I'm guessing this is an Apple bug, and will file a radar with them.  However, any workarounds would be appreciated.

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: we've never heard of this before with Universal Links. When you say it ceases to work after a reboot, is that permanent? Does it completely stop working (you don't see the app with a long-press on the link in Notes), or just get deactivated?

Comment: I don't see the app with long press in notes anymore.  If I check the AASA validator, the info on the site is still correct.  It just appears that the app side of the equation is deactivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had not seen this issue at Branch when Alex wrote his comment above. We have since confirmed that this is indeed an Apple bug.

Answer (score 0):

Current documentation states you need to uninstall the app every time you update Associated Domains list to apply the effect immediately.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains_in_your_app